# Why is stringr::str_detect not able to detect my string?

Tags: r, regex, unicode, stringr

I am extracting lines from a pdf, and trying to detect a specific string with `dplyr::filter(stringr::str_detect(my_column, 'my string'))`.

The string does not seem to have an encoding that is detectable.

Here is a link to the PDF file: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/Rsubread/inst/doc/SubreadUsersGuide.pdf

The string is the em-dash in the table (left hand column) on page 42.

I have tried detecting several representations of the em-dash, but cannot find the one in this document.

How can I determine the encoding of this em-dash so that I can filter my tibble with it?

```
pdftools::pdf_text("SubreadUsersGuide.pdf") %>% 
  stringr::str_split(pattern = '\r') %>% 
  tibble::tibble(
    line = .
  ) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(cols = line) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(
    stringr::str_detect(line, pattern = '^EM_DASH')
  )
```

Comment: Try `pattern = '[\\p{Pd}\\xAD]'`, or if it should be at the start of a string, `pattern = '^[\\p{Pd}\\xAD]'`

Comment: Hi, @WiktorStribiżew, the regex you provide does detect the single dashes, but not the em-dashes.

Comment: Do you mean `−−donotsort`? That is a minus sign, not a dash, use `^[\\p{Pd}\\xAD\\u2212]+` where `\u2212` matches the minus sign.

Comment: There are several I wish to extract on pages 42-43 (−−fracOverlap to −−verbose). I am hoping they all have the same encoding. That worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character you want to match is not a dash, it is a [`MINUS` sign](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm) belonging to the [*Symbol, Math*](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sm/list.htm) Unicode category, with `U+2212` code.

To match any one or more Unicode dashes + MINUS signs at the start of  a string, you may use

```
pattern = "^[\\p{Pd}\\xAD\\u2212]+"
```

Here,

- `^` - start of string
- `[` - start of a character class:

  - `\p{Pd}` - any [*Puncutation, Dash*](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm) char
  - `\xAD` - a soft hyphen
  - `\u2212` - a MINUS sign.
- `]+` - end of a character class, one or more occurrences.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iY2Huk/1).